# In Ruby on Rails, does a child class inherit the parent class' associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an abstract class called `Work` and another class I called `Fanfic`. In the `Fanfic` model, I had that it `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :characters` along with other associations. I decided that it would be easier when I add more classes that they will be subclasses of `Work` instead of having all of the types of works as totally separate classes.

Now I'm wondering if I could write the associations ALL of the works would have in the `Work` model, with all of the sub-classes keeping all of those associations as well.

Sorry if it's a bit confusing. Let me know if you need clarification or if you need to see my code, or if you need any other information.

Comment: Yes, descendants of a class will inherit its methods (associations, among others)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only should you define associations in `Work` (super) class (and they will be usable in subclasses), you should also use `works` table for all the subclasses of `Work`.

It's typical case of [Single Table Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance).

To enable it, you just need to add `type` column to `works` table (add migration for it).

When you query for `Tales`, for instance, Rails creates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM WORKS WHERE type='Tale';
```

There is a great (and consice) writeup about this concepts in Rails documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: I noticed that, and thought I would maybe do that, but what if there are two subclasses, and they have different columns. like lets say all works have the `title` column, but only `fanfics` have the `chapters` column. Could I still do the single table inheritance? And if so, Would all of the other subclasses of works have the `chapters` column/field?

Comment: @l1zZY you always extend `works` table. So, if you add column to subclass, it will be accessible from the superclass and other subclasses too.